# calculating the first three HIGHEST GPA of each school

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have calculated the HIGHEST GPA scored by student from each school. But how can I get the list of top 3 GPA, I mean `RANK 1, 2, and 3` scored by students from each school ?

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT B.SCHOOL_NAME
        ,C.STUDENT_NAME
        ,A.SYMBOL_NO
        ,A.AVG_GPA
        ,MAX(A.AVG_GPA) OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME) AS MAX_GPA
    FROM TBL_STUDENT_MARKS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL B ON A.SCHOOL_ID = B.SCHOOL_ID
    INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT_INFO C ON A.SYMBOL_NO = C.SYMBOL_NO
        AND B.SCHOOL_ID = C.SCHOOL_ID
    ) A
WHERE A.AVG_GPA = MAX_GPA
ORDER BY A.AVG_GPA DESC;
```

Comment: Have you considering add `RANK` to your sub query and then including that column in the `WHERE` of your outer query? Also [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` and `PARTITION BY` in combination:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY <expr1>[{,<expr2>...}]
    ORDER BY <expr1> [ASC|DESC], [{,<expr2>...}]
)
```

In this case something like

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME ORDER BY AVG_GPA desc) AS SCHOOL_RANK
```

and then in the outer query you add

```
WHERE SCHOOL_RANK in (1, 2, 3)
```

**Also**

Give Common Table Expressions a look! I find it often nicer than nested `SELECT`.

```
WITH ranked as (
    SELECT 
        SCHOOL_ID 
        , SYMBOL_NO
        , AVG_GPA
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SCHOOL_ID ORDER BY AVG_GPA DESC) AS SCHOOL_RANK 
    FROM TBL_STUDENT_MARKS
)
SELECT 
    SC.SCHOOL_NAME
    , INFO.STUDENT_NAME
    , ST.SYMBOL_NO
    , ST.AVG_GPA
    , ST.SCHOOL_RANK 
FROM ranked ST
INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL SC ON R.SCHOOL_ID = SC.SCHOOL_ID
INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT_INFO INFO ON ST.SYMBOL_NO = INFO.SYMBOL_NO AND SC.SCHOOL_ID = INFO.SCHOOL_ID
WHERE SCHOOL_RANK <= 3
ORDER BY SCHOOL_NAME, SCHOOL_RANK;
```

Comment: True, dense_rank is better :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How can I apply CTE here for the result?

Comment: Added the syntax :)

Comment: Did it help you @nischalinn? Or did you use some other answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either RANK() or DENSE_RANK() or ROW_NUMBER() to achieve the result.
However, RANK() and DENSE_RANK() are preferable for this scenario.

RANK():

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT B.SCHOOL_NAME
         ,C.STUDENT_NAME
         ,A.SYMBOL_NO
         ,A.AVG_GPA
         ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME ORDER BY A.AVG_GPA DESC) AS SCHOOL_RANK
    FROM TBL_STUDENT_MARKS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL B ON A.SCHOOL_ID = B.SCHOOL_ID
    INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT_INFO C ON A.SYMBOL_NO = C.SYMBOL_NO AND B.SCHOOL_ID = C.SCHOOL_ID
) A
WHERE SCHOOL_RANK <= 3
ORDER BY SCHOOL_NAME, SCHOOL_RANK
```

DENSE_RANK():

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT B.SCHOOL_NAME
         ,C.STUDENT_NAME
         ,A.SYMBOL_NO
         ,A.AVG_GPA
         ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME ORDER BY A.AVG_GPA DESC) AS SCHOOL_DENSE_RANK
    FROM TBL_STUDENT_MARKS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL B ON A.SCHOOL_ID = B.SCHOOL_ID
    INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT_INFO C ON A.SYMBOL_NO = C.SYMBOL_NO AND B.SCHOOL_ID = C.SCHOOL_ID
) A
WHERE SCHOOL_DENSE_RANK<= 3
ORDER BY SCHOOL_NAME, SCHOOL_DENSE_RANK
```

ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT B.SCHOOL_NAME
         ,C.STUDENT_NAME
         ,A.SYMBOL_NO
         ,A.AVG_GPA
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME ORDER BY A.AVG_GPA DESC) AS SCHOOL_ROW_NUMBER
    FROM TBL_STUDENT_MARKS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL B ON A.SCHOOL_ID = B.SCHOOL_ID
    INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT_INFO C ON A.SYMBOL_NO = C.SYMBOL_NO AND B.SCHOOL_ID = C.SCHOOL_ID
) A
WHERE SCHOOL_ROW_NUMBER <= 3
ORDER BY SCHOOL_NAME, SCHOOL_ROW_NUMBER
```

Please refer [here](https://codingsight.com/similarities-and-differences-among-rank-dense_rank-and-row_number-functions/) for the difference between Rank, DenseRank and RowNumber

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME ORDER BY A.AVG_GPA DESC)`

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT B.SCHOOL_NAME
        ,C.STUDENT_NAME
        ,A.SYMBOL_NO
        ,A.AVG_GPA
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME ORDER BY A.AVG_GPA DESC) 
         AS HIGHEST_GPA
    FROM TBL_STUDENT_MARKS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL B ON A.SCHOOL_ID = B.SCHOOL_ID
    INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT_INFO C ON A.SYMBOL_NO = C.SYMBOL_NO
        AND B.SCHOOL_ID = C.SCHOOL_ID
    ) A
WHERE HIGHEST_GPA <= 3
ORDER BY A.AVG_GPA DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Dense_rank window function:

```
 select  * 
    from(SELECT A.*,DENSE_RANK()over(partition by school_name order by MAX_GPA 
 desc)as  rankno
FROM (
    SELECT B.SCHOOL_NAME
           ,C.STUDENT_NAME
           ,A.SYMBOL_NO
           ,A.AVG_GPA
           ,MAX(A.AVG_GPA) OVER (PARTITION BY B.SCHOOL_NAME) AS MAX_GPA
     FROM TBL_STUDENT_MARKS A
     INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL B ON A.SCHOOL_ID = B.SCHOOL_ID
     INNER JOIN TBL_STUDENT_INFO C ON A.SYMBOL_NO = C.SYMBOL_NO
     AND B.SCHOOL_ID = C.SCHOOL_ID
     ) A
```

WHERE A.AVG_GPA = MAX_GPA )B
WHERE rankno IN(1,2,3);